# Dominance Hierarchy Algorithmic Solution

Tags: algorithm, bioinformatics

I am trying to calculate a non-linear/intransitive hierarchy structure from a dominance matrix  and wanted to know if there is an algorithmic solution to this problem, if so, could someone please provide the relevant algorithms.

The matrix has 20 different individuals each having interactions with each other with an outcome, there are a total of 82 interactions.

It would also be useful to know if anyone is aware of an existing solution/software for calculating a dominance hierarchy based on matrices.

I'd be happy to provide anymore information if necessary.

Comment: I suspect the solution could be to create a directed graph of all interactions and if it's a DAG, you can do a topological ordering on it. But I don't really know what should happen if the interactions contain a cycle.

Comment: you could also ask biostar: http://www.biostars.org/show/questions/

Comment: That site looks great, thanks guys.